# How do I format the string of a uicontrol to not use scientific notation?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I have a `popupmenu` using the `uicontrol` class within matlab.  However, the numbers that are greater than 1 million are expressed in scientific notation:

[image: That just looks weird]

This is generated using the following code:

```
sPropGrid = uiextras.Grid('Parent', staticPropPanel);
...
self.nSamplesEdit = uicontrol('Style', 'popupmenu', 'Parent', sPropGrid, ...
                'String', {[256 16384 32768 65536 131072 262144 524288 1048576 2097152 16252928]});
```

I would like to stop this, and display the entire number in normal formatting.  How do I do this?

Comment: Note: I've tagged this as [tag:matlab-guide] however I'm not specifically using GUIDE everywhere.  My main GUI is developed using the GUI Layout Toolbox.  However this specific issue is related to the MatLab object `uicontrol`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

imple example of :

```
f=figure;
L=uicontrol('parent',f,'style','popupmenu','string',{'1','2','6000000'});
```

Isn't showing this behaviour.

What code is generating these values? As popupmenu uses a cell array of strings to represent its value, it is likely that the code generating the GUI is using

```
sprintf('%0.5g',value);
```

Or something along those lines to input values to the popupmenu. If you change this to

```
sprintf('%d',value);
```

or

```
sprintf('%.0f',value);
```

for floating point values (although number of samples should be an integer, I imagine), it should have the behaviour you want.

Edit:

Addition to answer your extra info.

To use sprintf to format as you wish using a numerical array, you can use this syntax for arbitrary array X:

```
arrayfun(@(x) {sprintf('%d',x)},X);
```

So in your popupmenu you can use:

```
self.nSamplesEdit = uicontrol('Style', 'popupmenu', 'Parent', sPropGrid, ...
    'String', arrayfun(@(x) {sprintf('%d',x)},...
    [256 16384 32768 65536 131072 262144 524288 1048576 2097152 16252928]));
```